# Properly handle OutOfMemoryException throwing in different line every time

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

My c# app is OK to throw `OOM` from time to time (it allows user to retrieve data w/o using SQL `limit` command), and all I need is to handle it properly. `MessageBox` containing advice to use `limit` would be good enough.

Problem is that `OOM` is raised in different line everytime (same line with the same data being retrieved, but new data - new exception point): sometimes there is no free memory for GDI+ to do the painting, sometimes SQL connector fails, sometimes one of the wrapper-classes. Different lines, different classes, different event handlers, even different anonymous methods. It's not as bad as it sounds, class hierarchy is pretty legitimate and stuff, but I cant really make it simple enough to use only one (or even two) `try/catch` block (app is multithreaded btw).

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`/`Application.ThreadException` is no option (too late to handle).

Is there a way to properly handle the very first `OOM` that has been thrown by app ("the very first" because catching `OOM` around data-retrieval entry point leads to another `OOM`, e.g. due to attempt to clear `SortableBindingList`)? To handle it in such a way that no memory would be allocated elsewhere while you trying to force GC to do some work?

Comment: Are you running the program in release with the debugger detached? The GC will not collect objects (even if you tell it to do it explicitly with `GC.Collect()`) because the debugger itself is keeping the objects alive (otherwise things like the watch screen would not work reliably, so as long as a object could ***potentially*** be used in the watch window it won't be collected). Do you still get OOM errors if you don't have the debugger attached?

Comment: Also GDI+ will throw a `OutOfMemoryException` for non memory reasons. If you are not disposing your GDI objects you will run out of GDI resources and those do not automatically get collected like large objects would due to memory pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that the OOM is because the garbage collector isn't doing its job. More likely, it's because your application is using too much memory (or has too much memory fragmentation).

If the memory usage of your application is determined by user input, and if you cannot limit that user input to prevent OOM, then I recommend executing the failing code within a separate AppDomain. If that AppDomain fails, then your original AppDomain will still be in a good condition to handle the failure and inform the user "don't do that again".

Comment: No, GC does its job just fine. The idea is that OOM is acceptable, I'm just having trouble handle it properly due to raise point mobility first and need for new memory block allocation within any catch block countermeasures second. Come to think of it, I believe separate AppDomain should do the trick. Nasty trick, but seems to worth it, thanks!